# ffmpeg_concat is not running from shell_exec() function?

Tags: ffmpeg

command is running on CLI on Linux.

ffmpeg-concat -t circleopen -d 750 -o /var/www/html/testing_video/huzzah.mp4 /var/www/html/testing_video/1.mp4 /var/www/html/testing_video/2.mp4 /var/www/html/testing_video/3.mp4 2>&1

Perfectly working on CLI. But when i used with the shell_exec command from a php file it gives an error.

failed to create OpenGL context
at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/ffmpeg-concat/lib/context.js:24:11)
at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/ffmpeg-concat/lib/render-frames.js:19:21)
at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/ffmpeg-concat/lib/index.js:53:32)
at

Anyhow i debug the code function is calling and the parameters width and height is passing but still returning null.

Node version:v8.11.3